# Creating grouping variable in R

Tags: r

I've successfully written three independent flag commands, however when I try to combine them into one, it doesn't work!

The following three commands create a flag variable for ages 23, 24 and 25:

```
income_2017_18$agegroup23 <- 
ifelse(income_2017_18$age==23, 1, 0)

income_2017_18$agegroup24 <- 
ifelse(income_2017_18$age==24, 1, 0)

income_2017_18$agegroup25 <- 
ifelse(income_2017_18$age==25, 1, 0)
```

I'm trying to write a command that creates a flag whether a case is in either the 23, 24 or 25 age but I don't seem to be able to make it work:

```
income_2017_18$income2325 <- 
ifelse((income_2017_18$age==23) | 
(income_2017_18$age==24) | 
(income_2017_18$age==25), 1)
```

Grateful for any suggestions.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this help:

```
income_2017_18$income2325 <- 
ifelse(income_2017_18$age %in% 23:25, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `==`, we can use `%in%`

```
income_2017_18$income2325 <- ifelse(income_2017_18$age %in% c(23, 24, 25), 1, 0)
```

---

here, `ifelse` is not needed

```
+(income_2017_18$age %in% c(23, 24, 25))
```

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

@ John Wildman can you double check your output using the following code, I think you are just missing a 0 for the no match condition:

```
income_2017_18$income2325 <- 
  ifelse((income_2017_18$age==23) | 
           (income_2017_18$age==24) | 
           (income_2017_18$age==25), 1,0)
```

> Verified using the following data

```
income_2017_18 <- data.frame(age=19:30)
```

> Output

```
[1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

@akrun's approach is more concise and elegant.